Relation between minimality and algebraic independence for binomials?
$\DeclareMathOperator\supp{supp}$Given $f_1,...,f_n \in \mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_n]$ such that
$f_1 = x_1 + q_1$
$f_2 = x_2 + q_2$
$\cdot \cdot \cdot$
$f_{n-1} = x_{n-1} + q_{n-1}$
$f_{n} = q_n$
such that $deg(q_i) = 2$ and $q_i$ is a monomial, for all $i \in \{1,...,n \}$.
For $f = \sum_{l}a_l x_1^{l_1}\cdot \cdot x_n^{l_n}$, define $$\supp(f) = \{j \mid \exists l \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n \,,\; a_l \neq 0 \text{ and } l_j\neq 0 \}.$$
We say $f_1,...,f_n$ satisfy the minimality condition if for $1 \leq r \leq n-1$, any $r$ subset of distinct polynomials $f_{i_1},...,f_{i_r}$ we have $|\bigcup_j\supp(f_{i_j})| \geq r+1$.
My question is whether $f_1,...,f_n$ satisfying the minimality condition implies algebraic independence.I am mostly interested in the case $\mathbb{F} = \bar{\mathbb{F}}_2$ but would welcome insights about any general field. I conjecture it to be true, the idea I have been using is the following :
Let $lm(f)$ := least monomial of $f$ under some monomial ordering
then we can easily show that $\{lm(f_1),...,lm(f_n)\}$ being algebraically independent implies $\{ f_1,...,f_n \}$ is algebraically independent. I have been trying to show that under the minimality condition a weighted monomial ordering exists such that $\{lm(f_1),..., lm(f_n)\}$ becomes independent. Due to the minimality condition we also have there exists a perfect matching of $\{f_1,..,f_n\}$ onto $\{ x_1,...,x_n \}$ by Hall's Theorem on the support graph of the polynomial system.
